# Viewport height meta tag

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, breakpoints

I applied the following css:

```
@media screen and (max-height: 650px) {
    .about .info{
        bottom: 65px;
    }
}
```

In my html I wrote

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

But the breakpoint isn't working. I added the following:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="height=device-height, initial-scale=1.0">
```

That did not work either, so I removed the `"initial-scale=1.0"`, but that messes up the whole web page.

Any thoughts?

**UPDATE**

Here is my foreach loop where I add the images and the info.

```
<?php $i=0;?>
@foreach($images as $image)
<div class="about">
    <div class="overlay"></div>
    <div class="image" style="background-image:url({{asset('uploads/about/' . $image->path )}})">
        <section class="info right hidden" id="{{$i+1}}">
            <h2>{{$image->title}}</h2>
            <div>{{$image->body}}</div>
        </section>
    </div>
</div>
<?php $i++; ?>
@endforeach
```

and here is my full `<head>`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Kristal Logistics</title>
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="{{asset('img/favicon.png')}}" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        {{ HTML::style('fonts/fonts.css')}}
        {{ HTML::style('css/reset.css')}}
        {{ HTML::style('css/fullpage.css')}}
        {{ HTML::style('css/animate.css')}}
        {{ HTML::style('css/menu.css')}}
        {{ HTML::style('css/main.css')}}
        {{ HTML::script('js/jquery.js') }}
        {{ HTML::script('js/script.js') }}
        {{ HTML::script("js/modernizr.custom.js")}}
    </head>
    <body>
```

My css code posted above is applied in main.css at the very last line.

Comment: What do you mean with the breakpoint not working?

Comment: the div does not update ..

Comment: So when resizing the screen you see no change in the css as set in the @media? Possibly another css stylesheet might override your @media, please check the order in which your CSS files are being applied if you have multiple files.

Comment: No, that's not the issue. It's the very last CSS I have applied.

Comment: Could you post more HTML in your OP? For instance the HTML for the .about .info div, that way we can help better.

Comment: I recreated a part of your code in this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y7g2zomy/) and that works. Maybe other code for the parent divs keeps the section from responding correct. I added a position absolute to the content section, possibly try that.

Comment: That's definitely working here. Very strange..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65871/discussion-between-bastiaan-and-barto).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the order of the css files and the order for which the breakpoint is called. As mentioned in my comment, this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y7g2zomy/) shows a working example. In my example I added a

```
position:absolute;
```

to the content section. This ensures the correct positioning when the order of css is correct.